# How to cover gaps between cabinets?

Tags: kitchen-counters

We purchased our home not too long ago, and in the kitchen there's a large gap between the cabinets themselves. There's a whole open space back there, and we have cats so I've been trying to come up with ways to block it off. Temporarily, I covered it with a small, random piece of wood and some "caulking" tape and it worked until one of them discovered the board was still loose enough to move and got back there. I tried to google ideas but no matter what I look up it keeps pointing me to gaps between the counter and cabinet and I can't figure out the best way to do it permanently. For temporary measures I found out just putting a random piece of wood there doesn't really help because of the open space, it just falls over, and putting a larger piece in front of it sucks too because there's still space at the bottom. Picture featuring my beautiful tape work destroyed after I had to rip it apart to pull my cat out lol.

Comment: Please [edit[ your question and use the "sun & mountains" button to add a pic or 2.

Comment: Just placing wood/stuff in there won't work unless it is attached.  To be able to remove it in the future I would suggest silicon caulking to attach or screws.  Might need two pieces front and bottom.

Comment: Lacking a pic, you might just put custom sized cardboard boxes in there.